# Sync Adapter not started on Xiaomi

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-syncadapter

I've written a sync adapter in Xamarin but there is a problem under Xiaomi MiUI.

There are two methods of sync adapter starting : one is "settings->accounts->synchronize" via phone, the other is in the application with the aid of ContentResolver.RequestSync().

First of all, I had to switch on the MiUI AutoStart for my application.  Otherwise the security system wrote down error to log.

> I/AutoStartManagerService: MIUILOG- Reject service :Intent { act=android.content.SyncAdapter cmp=com.fingrad.dashboard/.AdapterService (has extras) } userId : 0 uid : 10186 
>   E/SyncManager: Bind attempt failed - target: ComponentInfo {com.fingrad.dashboard/com.fingrad.dashboard.AdapterService}

Nevertheless, the first method doesn’t work unless the application process is been already in the phone memory. 
The second method doesn’t work if the SyncAdapterService has not empty the Process attribute. See the example below.

```
[Service(Name = "com.fingrad.dashboard.SyncAdapterService"  
, Exported = true, Process = ":sync")] 
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.content.SyncAdapter" })] 
[MetaData("android.content.SyncAdapter", Resource = "@xml/syncadapter")] 
class SyncAdapterService : Service
```

In other words, adapter doesn't work if any of conditions is true.
1) Adapter service has Process attribute
2) There is no application instance in the phone memory.

It's obvious that the source of problem is MiUI security. MiUI starting sync adapter, starts another process which doesn't have autostart permission. I've tried to set “Process="application default process name", but it hasn’t helped.

**UPDATE** P.S Time passed but problem remains. Redmi Note 4, MIUI 9.5, Android 7 and Redmi Note 3, MIUI 9.5, Android 6.

Comment: Have you tried disabling "MIUI optimization", inside developer settings?

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein, yes, I tryed.

Comment: how about the solution/explanation given here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312076/997940 (from my expereince, you might need to revoke permissions and than grant them again, for both Startup and Notifications Access)

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein, I did it many times without success. The problem is only for Mi4i. It seems the other xiaomi work well.

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein, It seems to me I found out how to force to do MIUI start syncservice. Besides startup permission you need choose 'no restrictions' at the battery saver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out how to force MIUI start Sync Adapter.
You have to do following:

1. Open Settings -> Installed app
2. Choose your application
3. Switch on autostart
4. Switch off any battery saver restrictions

[image]

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks! I had to wait quite some time until the change actually took effect though..

Comment: Took me a couple restarts after tweaking these settings, but my sync adapter finally ran!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two option to fix this issue

**1 ONE**

```
     <service
            android:name="com.example.android.datasync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
     </service>
```

Remove **android:process=":sync"** from android manifest

**2 TWO**

You have to do following:

- Open Settings -> Installed app
- Choose your application
- Switch on autostart
- Done

Answer (score 0):

In additional to the accepted answer, there are one option that solve problem: in Developer options enable **Turn on MIUI optimization** checkbox.